# postgres: run group by with conditions specific to each group condition?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Postgres 9.6. I have a user table:

```
 id                            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                          | character varying           |           | not null | 
 t_registered       | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

And I have an `action` table:

```
 actioned_by      | integer                     |           |          | 
 category         | character varying           |           | not null | 
 t_actioned       | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

I want a way to annotate each user with an integer field `num_days` that indicates for how many distinct 24 hour periods they have actions, in the 30 days after they registered.

I know how to get the total count of distinct calendar days on which each user was active:

```
 SELECT d.actioned_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM 
  (SELECT date_trunc('day', t_actioned) AS day, actioned_by 
   FROM history 
   GROUP BY day, actioned_by) d 
 GROUP BY actioned_by
 ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

But I'm stuck on how to get this in the 30 day time window specific to each user.

I suspect this is advanced SQL!

I'll just be running this occasionally for analytics purposes, so it doesn't really matter if it's slow.

Comment: I advice you to read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT actioned_by, COUNT(*)
FROM (
        SELECT actioned_by, date_trunc('day', t_actioned)
        FROM history
        JOIN user ON id = actioned_by
        WHERE t_actioned BETWEEN t_registered AND t_registered + interval '30 days'
        GROUP BY actioned_by, date_trunc('day', t_actioned)
) sub
GROUP BY actioned_by
```

So firstly you said you wanted to get a count of *distinct* days, so you must group on date_trunc otherwise you will count multiple events on the same day (if they exist).

What this query does is, join on `user` to get the registered timestamp for each user, make sure the `t_actioned` is within 30 days of registering, then group by user and unique date, and finally count per user.

If you want to include users with no actions then you can change it around slightly: select from the user table, and left join history:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM (
        SELECT id, date_trunc('day', t_actioned)
        FROM user
        LEFT JOIN history
            ON id = actioned_by
            AND t_actioned BETWEEN t_registered AND t_registered + interval '30 days'
        GROUP BY id, date_trunc('day', t_actioned)
) sub
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant! The only issue is that it doesn't pick up users who registered fewer than 30 days ago - ideally I'd like to include them too. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I'll have a look at it again in a bit, but just from looking at the code it appears to be correct - actioned date between the registered date and registered date + 30 days. Are you sure you have actions for those users? If they don't have actions then yes, they won't appear there, and it certainly can be changed to include them.

Comment: @Richard In any case I've updated the answer with another version of the query which will also get you users with no actions within that 30 day window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `COUNT` with `FILTER` expression:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u."name",
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE h.t_actioned BETWEEN u.t_registered AND u.t_registered + INTERVAL'30 days')
FROM 
    history h
    JOIN "user" u ON u.id = h.actioned_by
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    u."name"
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).